# compile linux into a binary to run a VM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, binary, user-mode-linux

I know there is a project that allows one to compile linux kernel into a (linux executable) binary that can be run from the linux host to create a guest VM.... I *always* forget the name of the project. What is it?

And is there an updated guide on how to get it working with current distros? I remember I tried to make it work a few months ago and instructions were kind of dated and was not able to make it work with images of distros I was creating with qemu, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.... got it. `uml` (from user-mode linux). http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/

I will see if this guide works (at least it is from last year): https://christine.website/blog/howto-usermode-linux-2019-07-07